# cmdstanR: inference on a bernouli parameter

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I built a simple model using a bernouli distribution in R using cmdstanR.

The stan file:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  int<lower=0, upper=1> obs_data[N];
}

parameters {
  real<lower=0, upper=1> lambda;
}

model {
  target += beta_lpdf(lambda | 1,1);
  for (n in 1:N) {
    target += bernoulli_logit_lpmf(obs_data[n] | lambda);
  }
}
```

Then I created 4 bernouli draws, with number of samples as 10, 100, 1000 and 10000.  I wanted to observe that with increasing number of data points, the uncertainty associated with the parameter goes down.

The r code is as follows:

```
extract_lambda_draws <- function(mod, obs_data, iter = 1) {

  dl <- list(N = length(obs_data), obs_data = obs_data)
  print(paste("Model build iteration: ", iter))

  fit <- mod$sample(data = dl, num_chains = 4, num_cores = 4)

  print("Model build competed ...")
  draws <- fit$draws()[,,1] %>% as_tibble() 
  return(round(draws,3))
}

num_tosses <- c(10, 100, 1000, 10000)

results <- tibble()

m <- cmdstan_model("coin-flip.stan")

for (i in num_tosses) {
  coin_tosses <- sample(c(0,1), i, replace = T, prob = c(0.4, 0.6))
  d <- extract_lambda_draws(m, coin_tosses, i)
  d <- d %>% mutate(iter = i)
  results <- rbind(results, d)
}

results %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(ends_with("lambda")), names_to = "chains", values_to = "lambda" ) %>% 
  mutate(chains = gsub(".lambda", "", chains)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = lambda)) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(iter~., nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
```

I get the following density distribution on the parameter

[image: bernouli draws expt1]

When I reverse the probability for 0 and 1 to c(0.6, 0.4), I get the following

[image: bernouli daraws expt2]

I have 2 questions:

1. When I create samples from c(0,1) with probability c(0.4, 0.6). I expect lambda to be around 0.6, atleast for the dataset with 10,000 samples. However the posterior mode is ~0.4.
2. When I create samples from c(0,1) with probability c(0.6, 0.4). I expect lambda to be around 0.4, atleast for the dataset with 10,000 samples. The posterior mode is close to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you use a *logit*-Bernoulli distribution.

Then, in the first situation, the posterior concentrates about:

```
> car::logit(0.6)
[1] 0.4054651
```

In the second situation, one has:

```
> car::logit(0.4)
[1] -0.4054651
```

But your prior distribution on *logit(p)* is restricted to the range (0,1). So the posterior is also restricted to this range, and then it concentrates at 0.

I don't know whether there is a function for the Bernoulli distribution parametrized by *p* in Stan.
But you could do something like that (I'm not sure of the syntax):

```
parameters {
  real<lower=0, upper=1> p;
}
transformed_parameters {
  lambda = log(p/(1-p)) // not sure of the syntax here
}
model {
  target += beta_lpdf(p | 1,1);
  for (n in 1:N) {
    target += bernoulli_logit_lpmf(obs_data[n] | lambda);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the catch and super quick response.  I changed the target in the stan code to **bernoulli_lpmf** instead of **bernoulli_logit_lpmf**, and the results are inline with the expectation.